# Calling Micro service inside a micro service

Tags: azure, microservices

**Microsoft - Micro service architecture**

Could it be reliable to call multiple micro services from a single micro service?

If I have developed 2 different micro services of customers and orders with their own database (i.e. customer db and order db), and if I would like to get combined data of customers and orders, what would be the best option to do that?

We want simply call one microservice which will call 2 separate microservices of customers and orders and combined their data and return a response of our choice. Is this usage is true?

In another way, we will call 2 separate micro services from our application side and combined data there.

I would like to get an option with the best performance, reliable and standard approach to do this process.

Can anyone tell me what would be options ?

and one more thing performance would be better in both side like in micro service response and in application side as well,

If other options are available then also please specify.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how [resilient](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) you want your system to be but it boils down to two type of communication: synchronous or asynchronous.

For **lesser resilience but a simpler architecture** you could use synchronous communication. In this architecture when a microservice fails then all the dependent microservices would also fail. You should use the [Circuit breaker](http://microservices.io/patterns/reliability/circuit-breaker.html) or [Bulkheads](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/designing-bulkheads-microservices-architecture-subhash-chandran/) patterns.

For a **greater resilience but a more complex architecture** you should use an asynchronous communication style. In this style the microservices could communicate using [messages](http://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/messaging.html).

Comment: I disagree that using messages is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to achieve it in microservices architecture.**

****1. API composition** :** Where you can call individual owner services to get the data and maintain it in memory. The only drawback is if there are frequent updates then it will act as a bottleneck for the performance.

****2. CQRS** :** This is a better solution in which the service which combines the data subscribes to the data owner services through an event queue. In case of any update rather then pulling the data periodically, the service which combines the data look for the domain/update event in the queue and refresh the data accordingly. The event is posted by the data owner services.